# What's the best free WebDav service out there?

Tags: webdav

Question says it all: there must be one that stands a head-and-shoulders above the rest...which is it?  I've got a few bits of software that would like to store syncable data on a WebDav server...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Box.net](https://www.box.net/) comes highly recommended. Webdav access is available through https://www.box.net/dav - but only for paying customers.

Their free Lite account will give you 1 GB of storage, though individual files cannot be larger than 25 MB each.

Comment: I knew about box.net but I had had ify experiences with it.  Since no-one else has offered an alternative I'll accept your answer...

Comment: +1 for Box.net.  They're very good.

Answer (score 1):

Apache's [mod_dav](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dav.html) has worked well for me.

Comment: Yeah, its true I guess...It means setting up a web server though...was hoping more for a free service.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at: http://www.ajaxfilebrowser.com/. No registration is needed it will automatically create a folder for you when you access it first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can give http://dropdav.com/ a try. It enables to access a dropbox account with WebDAV.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try 4shared.com
http: //webdav.4shared.com:80/wa
you can get 15GB for free
But the webdav works only for WinXP or Linux
Link to get it working
http://www.4shared.com/faq.jsp#q36

Answer (score 0):

Update: box.net does not offer free WebDAV anymore, sorry. You should try other providers. I use **http://www.cloudsafe.com** - they offer 2GB of free online storage and **free WebDAV access** can be easily enabled for every safe.